# Get the 2nd value of a variable that has 7 values separated by comma

Tags: php

In a variable `$price` I have those values separated by comma. Each one represent a day.

```
1st value,2nd value,3rd value,4th value,5th value,6th value,7th value
```

If I have a `$day` variable can I find the value ? What I mean is like
`if ($day == "Monday")` echo the 2nd value of `$price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pricePerDay = array_combine(array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'),
                             explode(',', $price));
echo $pricePerDay['Mon'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the function `explode(',',$price);` and use that to help you out.  You'll need a loop to get through the values and determine if it is the specific day.

Comment: Loops are for people that like doing things the hard way.

Comment: True, fiogkos could just right out seven if statements as well.

Comment: Sure, but that would be an even bigger waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$var="1st value,2nd value,3rd value,4th value,5th value,6th value,7th value";

$var_exploded=explode(",",$var);
```

if you want second value

```
echo $var_exploded[1];
```